# In Swift, how can I store the user's location inside a variable when I press a button?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

In the main `UIViewController`, I want to store the coordinates of the user in a variable when they press a `UIButton`. This variable will be used in another `UIViewController` with a `MapView`.

I tried setting up a `locationManager()`, but I could not get the button to work with it. Can anyone help?

Comment: "I tried setting up a locationManager(), but I could not get it working" Well, there's your problem. No location manager, no location. Get it working!

Comment: But... That's my question... How do I get it to work with a button press?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code that will help you:

```
var location: CLLocation! //to store location
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    _locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    // adjsut _locationManager
    return _locationManager
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

@IBAction func buttonDidClick(sender: AnyObject) { //event handler
    location = locationManager.location //set current location
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MyViewControllerSegue" { //before showing controller
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        dvc.location = location //set the current location
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I may have been initializing it wrong. Inside viewDidLoad() I could refer to the locationManager fine, but then my button event handler did not recognize it.

Comment: Do you mean that event handler doesn't raise at all?

Comment: When I refer to the locationManager inside the event handler, it does not recognize the manager. I will try initializing it as you have shown. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: I edited some code about location manager init, please look at this lazy init approach

Comment: Thank you! I will work with this, and mark this is correct. I really appreciate the time by the way. I'm new to development and appreciate the help without chastising :)

Comment: You are welcome! Do not hesitate to add relevant question comments on that topic

Comment: You do _not_ want to use lazy instantiation with location manager. If doing it lazily, `location` will almost certainly be `nil` (on a real device, anyway). So, set delegate, start location services, continue receiving updates until you have a location of sufficient accuracy, and then if you don't continue to need updates, turn off location services. Also, Cody, you probably want to check permissions, too (e.g. if denied and if really necessary for use of app, warn user). Also, Azat, I know you know this, but for Cody's benefit, remember to set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in plist.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Rob. The combination of both of your input has helped me solve it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rob thank you for comment, I just added code to `viewDidLoad` to show how lazy init may be helpful. It is very nice approach to have all adjustment code in one property and at the all other places you just call this property and you sure that there is a valid object/value. And it is true for `locationManager` too